# Headers Properties Issue

Tags: angular

I have a function that sends an email when the user submits the form

```
sendEmail() {

   let url = `the url placeholder`
   let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
   let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
   let message = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " has submitted the following form: " + this.cons.name;

   params.set('to', 'email placeholder');
   params.set('from', 'email placeholder');
   params.set('subject', 'A user has submitted a form');
   params.set('content', message);

   return this.http.post(url, params, headers)
                   .toPromise()
                   .then( res => {
                     console.log(res)
                   })
                   .catch(err => {
                     console.log(err)
                   })

 }
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR in src/app/ownership-cost/ownership-form.component.ts(281,39): error TS2559: Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
```

I recently upgraded my angular app from 4.1.3 to 5.2.0, so I'm not sure if this is causing the issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try: `return this.http.post(url, params, {headers})`

Comment: that worked, but why the need for the curly braces?

Comment: It needs to be an object with a property of `headers`. `{headers}` is just syntactic sugar for `{ headers: headers }`

Comment: Btw you don't need to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your angular app; that's a server side issue. Including it could cause CORS issues if that header is not exposed with 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers`